# Is Android Developer Options -> Stay Awake == FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or WAKE_LOCK?

Tags: java, android

I am building an app on an Android Nexus 10 tablet and it will serve as a kiosk, so I would like the screen to be on 100% of the time. I've been currently using Developer Options > Stay Awake (screen will ever sleep while charging).

Per this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

When this setting is enabled, is it equivalent to WAKE_LOCK or merely FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's more low-level than that. The "Stay Awake" toggle puts a value in Settings.Global, which is then read by the PowerManagerService. That value is a combination of the different plug-types that could be charging the phone (the switch uses AC, USB and WIRELESS by default).

If the stored value isn't `0`, and the device is plugged into one of the plug types specified by that value, the PowerManagerService just never sets the device to the ASLEEP state.

It's similar to a wakelock, but it has its own special process.

[StayAwakePreferenceController](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/development/StayAwakePreferenceController.java)
[PowerManagerService](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java)

---

By the way, FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON actually uses a wakelock behind the scenes. You just don't need to hold the WAKELOCK permission to use it.

You can see that [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/RootWindowContainer.java#L729) and [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService.java#L5618).

---

For a kiosk-type thing, you should probably use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON. This wakelock prevents the screen from dimming, while the "Stay Awake" toggle doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your second point is helpful as well, as I'd read that somewhere else, but had trouble locating a source.